# Can WinJS xhr make HTTPS request?

Tags: javascript, win-universal-app, winjs, windows-10-universal

For example it needs to call a web service hosted with SSL.

If it can, how to pass the client certificate then?

Thanks a lot!!

```
      WinJS.xhr({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "https://localhost:442/WebService1.asmx?op=Login",

                }).then(function success(res) {                       
                    var debug1 = res.responseText + res.responseURL; 

                }, function error(err) {
                    var debug2 = err.responseText + err.responseURL;                        
                }, function completed(result) {
                    if (result.status === 200) {                       
                      // do something
                    }
                });
```

The debugging point will jump to 'complete(result)' function, but the status code is '0'. Even if I change URL to other https site (e.g. https://www.w3.org), result is the same.

**------------- Update 1 ---------------------**

If it's in C# I could use following code to pass client certificate. However if I want to change origial WinJs.xhr to HttpClient, just copy & paste seems not working as .js file could not understand all syntax?

```
var certQuery = new CertificateQuery();     
var cert = (await CertificateStores.FindAllAsync(certQuery)).FirstOrDefault(c=>c.Issuer.StartsWith("xxxx",StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
var filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
if (cert != null)  
{
filter.ClientCertificate = cert; 
filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.Untrusted | ChainValidationResult.InvalidName);
}                    

var hc = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient(filter);
var uri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri(url);
hc.getStringAsync(uri).done({.......});
```

E.g.

1) How to write 'Using .... ' in JS file?

2) How to use "await" or "'FindAllAsync'" in this line? etc.

```
var cert = (await CertificateStores.FindAllAsync(certQuery)).FirstOrDefault(c=>c.Issuer.StartsWith("xxxx",StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Answer (score 1):

`WinJS.xhr` wraps `XMLHttpRequest`( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229787.aspx ) with a `Promise`-like interface (a WinJS `Promise`, not an ES6 `Promise`, but the concept is similar).

`XMLHttpRequest` has the `withCredentials` property which allows you to specify whether client-side credentials, including client-side certificates, should be sent or not - but there is no API that would allow you to specify which specific client-side certificate should be used.

Fortunately WinJS exposes the `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient` type which gives you more control over client authentication, including client-side certificates - but your UWP application must have "Enterprise capability" to use the user's `My` certificate store - otherwise non-Enterprise UWP applications only have certificates in their Application Certificate Store:

https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/11/23/demystifying-httpclient-apis-in-the-universal-windows-platform/#Dr3C9IMHv5pTPOrB.97

> You must first add it to the app’s certificate store by following [these instructions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2014/07/31/programmatically-create-and-configure-a-client-certificate-for-use-in-your-windows-runtime-based-app.aspx). Apps with enterprise capability can also use existing client certificates in the user’s ‘My’ store.

Comment: Hi Dai, 1st question: as my current project (Enterprise) was written many years ago and all use WinJS.xhr to make web service call, is there any other easy way to pass client certificate? ( besides using HttpClient object in C# code)

Comment: Hello Dai, 2nd question: as I am new to UWP, could you please explain a little bit more about what you said above " your client certificate must have 'Enterprise capability' to use the user's My certificate store"? For example: how to generate a client-certificate with 'Enterprise capability' and what is "User's My certificate store"? Thanks again!

Comment: @Samuel It was a typing error in my posting, I have corrected it now.

Comment: Hi @Dai, could you please have a look at my updated code, I wrote in C# before and when paste to .js file to replace original WinJs,xhr call, it complains about some syntax.

Comment: @Samuel JavaScript/WinJS and C# are not source-compatible. You will need to write it correctly.